# Semantics - binomial vs binary

Tags: probability

Currently reading through some basic probability theory, and have reached a chapter on **binomial probability**.

The name irks me, because my understanding is that it is essentially **binary** in nature (*i.e. two possible outcomes*).

Is it jsut that binomial the word used by *mathematicians* and binary the one used in *software*? Or am I missing something?

Comment: If it helps, the binomial distribution is obtained by iterating a [Bernoulli Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) which does indeed concern trials with exactly two possible outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

"Binomial" comes from the expansion of a two variable exponential expression, via the Binomial Theorem.

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$$

The coefficient, $\binom nk$, is thusly known as the "binomial coefficient", and is the count of ways to select a subset of $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements.   It also counts distinct arrangements of a string of $k$ items of one type and $n-k$ items of another, when the items are considered indistinguishable except by type.

A Binomial random variable is the count of successes in a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate.   When $n$ is the amount of trials and $p$ the success rate, then the probability mass function is:$$\mathsf P(X=k)=\dbinom nk p^k(1-p)^{1-k}\qquad\Big[k\in \{0,.., n\}\Big]$$

This is derived by counting distinct arrangements of a sequence of $k$ successes and $n-k$ failures and multiplying by the probability of obtaining any particular sequence.

As you can see, this is a term in the binomial expansion of $(p+(1-p))^n$, and indeed:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \mathsf P(X=k) = \sum_{k=0}^n \dbinom nk p^k(1-p)^{1-k} = 1$$

---

PS: A Bernoulli trial is a single succeed-or-fail trial.   The count of successes in a single Bernoulli trial is itself a Binomial Random Variable, and one which can realise only two values: $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

To sum up Graham Kemp's nice and detailed explanation and give a to the point answer to your confusion:

Binary: Has two possible outcomes (e.g. 1/0, or flip of a coin)

Binomial: Count of outcomes in n binary trials (e.g. number of heads in 10 coin flips, number of 1's in a random binary number of length 8).

As you can see, a binomial random variable can have values other than 1/0, depending on its exact parameters. In the degenerate case where n=1 trial, a "binomial" is a "binary" (it is called a Bernoulli actually).

Disclaimer: The above is worded for intuitive understanding and not for mathematical rigor.

Answer (score 0):

The etymology of "binomial" is "having two parts", from bi- ("having two") and nomos (ancient Greek for "part, portion").